# Comparision of range projections of elements in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $a,b\in M$. Suppose $a\geq b$, then we have $R_a\geq R_b$, where $R_a$ is the range projection of $a$ and $R_b$ is the range projection of $b$.

According to the definition of $R_b$, $R_b$ is the smallest projection such that $R_b b=b$. If we prove that $R_ab=b$, then we can conclude that $R_a\geq R_b$.

My question is that how to deduce that $R_ab=b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are positive elements with $a\geq b$, then,
for every $n\in {\mathbb N}$, we have that
$$
  c_n:= (1-a^{1/n})b^{1/2} \quad {\buildrel n\to 0 \over
\longrightarrow} \quad 0,
  $$
because
$$
  c_nc_n^* =
  (1-a^{1/n})b(1-a^{1/n}) \leq
  (1-a^{1/n})a(1-a^{1/n}) \to 0.
  $$
Therefore
$$
  a^{1/n}b^{1/2} \to  b^{1/2}.
  $$
Denoting by $\bar R(x)$ the closure of the range of an operator
$x$, and observing that $\bar R(a^{1/n}) = \bar R(a)$, we deduce from the above that
$$
  \bar R(b^{1/2}) \subseteq  \bar R(a),
  $$
but since   $\bar R(b^{1/2}) = \bar R(b)$,  we get
$\bar R(b)\subseteq  \bar R(a)$, whence the conclusion.

Comment: How to check $\bar R(a^{1/n}) \subset \bar R(a)$?

Comment: Write $x^{1/n}$ as the uniform limit of polynomials $p_n(x)$ without constant term, over the spectrum of $a$.  Then $a^{1/n}=\lim p_n(a)$, and the range of $p_n(a)$ is contained in the range of $a$.

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions for range projections, can we prove $R_ab=b$

Comment: If you know that $R_{a^{1/n}}=R_a$, then
$$
R_ab^{1/2}=\lim R_a a^{1/n}b^{1/2} =
\lim a^{1/n}b^{1/2} = b^{1/2},
$$
so
$$
R_ab = R_ab^{1/2}b^{1/2} = b^{1/2}b^{1/2} =b.
$$